# My realtime tracking kml maps make a lag in the refresh

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, kml

Hi i develop a map to update a dynamic kml to refresh every 10 seconds but the function make a lag in the refresh this is the function to refresh the map is working but  the lag

```
 var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    'preserveViewport': true,
                    url: 'http://190.216.202.35/control/patiosvb.xml?o='+ Math.random()
                });

                ctaLayer.setMap(map);
                ctaLayer.set('preserveViewport', true);




                window.setInterval( function() {
                    reload();
                }, 10000);

                function reload() {
                    ctaLayer.setMap(null);
                    var mctaURL = 'http://190.216.202.35/control/patiosvb.xml?o='+ Math.random()
                    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(mctaURL, {

                    });
                    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
                    ctaLayer.set('preserveViewport', true);
                }


                ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

the map is hosted in

190.216.202.35/control/patiosp.html

tnks for any help to improve the code to eliminate the lag

pd: i think to work with a third party perhaps

Comment: Maybe setting the new layer before you remove the old one?

Comment: I'm curious, where are getting you data from? This is some traffic control site where you see if there is traffic jam or not?

Comment: I don't think use third party libraries with google.maps is a good idea, because this guys (Google) have already put all there, and is a very simple and best long term solution to do the tiny final step by oneself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the [`status_changed`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) event which : "*(This even) is fired when the KML layer has finished loading. At this point it is safe to read the status property to determine if the layer loaded successfully.*"

So is at this point you have to remove the *old kml layer* and *add* the newest layer.

Consider the following exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>Kml Layer</title>
       <style type="text/css">
            html,  body{height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
            #map-container{ height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width:500px; min-height:300px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-container"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">
            var map;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.4199865, -76.519775),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-container")[0], mapOptions);

                var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    'preserveViewport': true,
                    url: 'http://190.216.202.35/control/patiosvb.xml?o=' + Math.random()
                });

                ctaLayer.setMap(map);
                ctaLayer.set('preserveViewport', true);

                setInterval(function () {reload(); }, 10000);

                var ctaLayerTmp;

                function reload() {

                    var mctaURL = 'http://190.216.202.35/control/patiosvb.xml?o=' + Math.random()
                    ctaLayerTmp = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: mctaURL
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayerTmp, "status_changed", function() {
                        ctaLayer.setMap(null);
                        ctaLayerTmp.set('preserveViewport', true);
                        ctaLayer = ctaLayerTmp;                     
                    });
                    ctaLayerTmp.setMap(map);
                }
                ctaLayer.setMap(map);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have the green,yellow, red routes you have in your example, I guess is another layer your are loading elsewhere.

Comment: the red yellow green is a trafic layer of google.
thanks for the answer and your logic is correct but your example do not work the bus is letting a shadow and eventually the application breakout but the use of jquery is interesting

Comment: I edited the code. Now it is not letting a shadow. I forgot to change the temp layer by the actual layer, so after the temp layer was loaded and bound to the map it was not removed in the futures bounds.

Comment: wow is perfect thanks haha but sorry for abuse your trust you know a way to display labels?